# Unexpected token ::

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I get an error says:"Unexpected token, expected ;" and points the error caused by ::. And my code shown below. Can someone help me on this?

```
function wrapper(fn, name) {
    return function (...args) {
        debug(name, ...args);
        return this::fn(...args);
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you have the stage 0 preset installed?

Comment: if you use webpack, you should show us the webpack config

Comment: try `this.find.call(this, ...args);` or `this.find.apply(this, args);`

Comment: @AndrewLi no, I used to set it to stage 3. And now I changed to stage 0.

Comment: @AnthonyKong I donot use webpack and eventually I fixed it by installing babel function binding plugin and config it in .babelrc.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the cause and fixed it by install babel function binding plugin and config it in .babelrc

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/